# If the induced homomorphism is injective, then the morphism is dominant.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is well-known that a morphism $\varphi : X \to Y$  of affine varieties $X, Y$  is dominant if and only if the induced homomorphism $\varphi^* : A(Y) \to A(X)$ is injective.

But I'd like to show that this is true for quasi-affine case.

> a morphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ of **quasi-affine** varieties $X, Y$ is dominant if and only if and only if 
> the induced homomorphism $\varphi^* : \mathscr{O}(Y) \to \mathscr{O}(X)$ is injective.

I've shown that the case from dominantness to injectivity.

But I've stucked in the other implication, here is what I've tried.

If $\varphi$ were not dominant, then there would be $Z := \overline{\varphi(X)} \subsetneq Y$. (the inclusion should be strict.)

So there exists $y \in Y \setminus Z$, which is not in the image of $\varphi$.

And there exists a principal open subset $D(f)$ of $y$ containted in $Y \setminus Z$, where $f \in k[\bar{Y}]$. ($\bar{Y}$ is the Zariski closure of $Y$ in the ambient space.)

This means that $f(y) \neq 0$.

And I can't see how to proceed. Could you give me a hint ?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: What can you say about $\varphi^{\ast}f$?

Comment: @Thorgott Since $D(f) = Y \setminus Z(f) \subset Y \setminus Z$, it follows that $Z \subset Z(f)$. So $f$ is identically zero on $Z = \varphi(X)$, i.e., $f(\varphi(x)) = 0$ for all $x \in X$. But $f(\varphi) = \varphi^*(f) = 0$, by injectivity of the induced homomorphism, $f = 0$. So $D(f) = \emptyset$ which is equivalent to say that $Z = Y$. Is this right?